# bind zone choking on IN TXT record added to subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

When I add this line to my zone record: `subdomain.example.org. IN TXT "some text here"`, my syslog reports the zone can't reload due to errors. `subodmain IN TXT "some text here"` also fails.

The zone reloads fine without this line.

Comment: Can you show the actual error (and actual record if the above is not it)?

Comment: in syslog, the error is ` dns_master_load: /etc/bind/zones/example.org.hosts:30: subdomain.example.org: CNAME and other data`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by actual record. You mean the non-anonymized one?

Comment: Sounds like the name where you try to add the `TXT` record is an alias (has a `CNAME` record). A name cannot both be an alias and have data of its own, so this is expected.

Comment: Use `named-checkzone` to test the zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message posted in the comments:

```
dns_master_load: /etc/bind/zones/example.org.hosts:30: subdomain.example.org: CNAME and other data
```

It appears that the name where you are trying to add the `TXT` record is an alias (has a `CNAME` record).
A name cannot both be an alias and have data of its own, so this error is the expected outcome if you try to add any other records.

(The `TXT` record listed in the question would otherwise be fine.)